# CSS selector for partial element name

Tags: css

Is there an asterix method of selecting elements like there is for element attributes? I have a bunch of Angular components and would like to select them on something like

```
*-modal {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Examples

```
<shopping-cart-modal></shopping-cart-modal> 
<address-edit-modal></address-edit-modal>
```

Comment: Surely that's not the rendered HTML? If it's not then I doubt this is possble.

Comment: no, you cannot do this for tag name

Comment: Bummer. Thanks guys.